# 管理ページのデータベース情報が出力されない。

Tags: php

自動販売機システムを作成しているのですが、
管理ページを開いたときにデータベース情報が出力されません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

前は出力されていたのですが、view(tool2.php)のSQL関数が動いていたという理由でした。
view(tool2.php)のSQL関数などの記述をcontroller(tool.php)に移しましたが、
管理ページを開いた時にデータベース情報が出力されなくなりました。
tool.phpの中の$dataの中身はvar_dumpで確認したところ入っていたのを確認済みです。
おそらくtool2.phpに$dataの中身が送れていないのが原因かと思われますが、(tool2.phpの中でvar_dumpを使い、中身を確認したがnullだった。)
$dataを送るやり方がいまいちわからないです。(もしかしたらrequire_onceの設定違いかもしれない?)
なお今使ってるCloud-9というシステムではデバッグツールはないので、そういう系のコメントは無視させていただきますのでご了承ください。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授お願い致します。
ソースコード
Model
functions.php
↓

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');

function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
            
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
        if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
             
             $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
        }
            
        }
        
            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_name, price, stock, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                return $err_msg;
                
                
            }
                
            }
    }


        
function update_drink($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

        if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
                $update_stock = (int)($_POST['update_stock']);

                $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $update_id;
                
                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                } else {
                   $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                   return $err_msg;
                }
                }
        }
}




function change_drink($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

        if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
            if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
                $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
                $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

                $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
                    
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
            }
        }
    }
    
}



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
    FROM drink_info_table';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

function complete_check_insert($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_update($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function validation_check($link) {
   $err_msg = [];
   if (!isset($_POST['new_name']) || (isset($_POST['new_name']) && $_POST['new_name'] === ""))  {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_price']) || (isset($_POST['new_price']) && $_POST['new_price'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_price'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_stock']) || (isset($_POST['new_stock']) && $_POST['new_stock'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_stock'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!empty($_POST["new_status"])) {
    if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 2) {
     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
    }
    }
return $err_msg;
}

function validation_check2($link) {
    if (!empty($_POST["update_stock"])) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['update_stock'])) !== 1){ 
     $err_msg = [];
     $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
     return $err_msg;
    }

}
}
```

Controller
tool.php
↓

```
<?php
$data = [];
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $err_msg = validation_check($link);
     if ($err_msg == [])   {
        $data = insert_drink($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_insert($link);
    }
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['renew'])) {
    $err_msg = validation_check2($link);
    if ($err_msg == [])  {
        $data = update_drink($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_update($link);
    }
    
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
        $data = change_drink($link);
        $complete_msg = change_drink($link);
    }
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p> 
    <?php }
    }
    
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ((array)$complete_msg as $comp) { ?>
            <p><?php print $comp; ?></p> 
    <?php }
    }
    $data = do_sql($link);

close_db_connect($link);
```

view
tool2.php
↓

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');?>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ((array)$data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" name="renew" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" name="change" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit"  name="change" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

その他
const.php
↓

```
<?php
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];
$data = [];

define('DB_HOST',   '');
define('DB_USER',   ''); 
define('DB_PASSWD', '');
define('DB_NAME',   '');

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Comment: 「もしかしたらrequire_onceの設定違いかもしれない?」…その通りです。

Answer (score 1):

[include](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.include.php)や[require](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.require.php)の仕様を理解していないようです。

include等のファイルの読み込みは読み込んだ時点でスクリプトが実行されます。

なので

```
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');
(中略)
$data = do_sql($link);
```

こうしてしまうと$dataの中身を取得する前にtool2.phpのHTMLが実行されてしまいます。

またrequire等で呼び出しても変数のスコープは変わりませんので、
グローバルで$dataを宣言すればそのままrequire先でも変数を利用できます。

簡単に行ってしまえばrequire等で呼び出すことと、
先のスクリプトをコピペして張り付けることは全く一緒です。

例
(1)require_onceで呼び出す
test.php

```
$word = "Hello World";
require_once("hoge.php");
$word2 = "Good Night";
```

hoge.php

```
echo $word;//Hello Worldと出力される
echo $word2;//これは出力されずにエラーになる
```

(2)require_onceを使わないパターン
test.php

```
$word = "Hello World";
echo $word;//Hello Worldと出力される
echo $word2;//これは出力されずにエラーになる
$word2 = "Good Night";
```

(1)と(2)は一緒。

それを踏まえて実装を試してみてください。

Comment: 今修正したら直りました。ありがとうございます。